# Normal p-complement and the Frattini subgroup

Tags: gr.group-theory

A normal subgroup $N$ of a finite group $G$ is said to be a normal $p$-complement if $(p,|N|)=1$ and there is a Sylow $p$-subgroup $P$ of $G$ such that $G=NP$. The definition of a normal $\pi$-complement, where $\pi$ is a set of primes, is similar. Now let $G$ be a solvable group and $A$ be a minimal normal subgroup of $G$.

**Question 1**: if $A$ is contained in the Frattini subgroup of $G$ and $G/A$ has a normal $p$-complement, can we conclude that $G$ also has a normal $p$-complement?

**Question 2**: if $A$ is contained in the Frattini subgroup of $G$ and $G/A$ has a normal $\pi$-complement, can we conclude that $G$ also has a normal $\pi$-complement?

Many thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Yes and yes - these seem like exercises.

Comment: It's not even necessary to assume $G$ solvable or that $A$ is minimal normal ( as long as $A \leq \Phi(G)$).

Comment: @Derek Holt and Geoff Robinson: Many thanks for your answer and comment. Could you please give me a hint to prove them.

Comment: This question would be more appropriate for math.stackexchange, and you would probably get more detailed help there. As a hint, use the Schur-Zassenhaus Theorem to get a complement of $A$ in $N/A$, and then use the Frattini Argument and Schur-Zassenhaus again on that complement.